# Specific column widths and alignment with savetxt

Tags: python, astronomy

I'm nearly finished with this program, but I can't get the output quite how I want it. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

filename = (raw_input("Which file are we loading?  "))
header = input("How many header lines?  ")

# Input variables for column numbers and limiting factors

pcol = input("What column number is parallax in?  ")
vcol = input("What column number is Vmag (or other limiting mag) in?  ")
pmcol = input("What column number does proper motion begin in (Mu/PA or MuRa MuDec format)  ")
ra = input("What column number is RA1 in? (h m s format)  ")
dec = input("What column number is Dec1 in? (d m s format)  ")
maglim = input("What is your limiting (dimmest) magnitude?  ")
parlim = input("What is your limiting (farthest) parallax?  ")

# Read in entire file

data = np.loadtxt(filename,skiprows=header,dtype=str)

# Select correct columns

parallax_str = data[:,pcol-1] 
ra1_str = data[:,(ra-1)]
ra2_str = data[:,(ra)]
ra3_str = data[:,(ra+1)]
dec1_str = data[:,(dec-1)]
dec2_str = data[:,(dec)]
dec3_str = data[:,(dec+1)]
vmag_str = data[:,vcol-1]
pm1_str = data[:,(pmcol-1)]
pm2_str = data[:,(pmcol)]

# Convert selected strings to floats

parallax = parallax_str.astype(float)
vmag = vmag_str.astype(float)
pm1 = pm1_str.astype(float)
pm2 = pm2_str.astype(float)

criteria = (parallax>=parlim) & (vmag<=maglim)
vmag = vmag[criteria]
parallax = parallax[criteria]
pm1 = pm1[criteria]
pm2 = pm2[criteria]
ra1_str = ra1_str[criteria]
ra2_str = ra2_str[criteria]
ra3_str = ra3_str[criteria]
dec1_str = dec1_str[criteria]
dec2_str = dec2_str[criteria]
dec3_str = dec3_str[criteria]


newlist = np.vstack((ra1_str,ra2_str,ra3_str,dec1_str,dec2_str,dec3_str,vmag,parallax,pm1,pm2))
newlist = newlist.T

np.savetxt('observe.list',newlist,fmt='%s')
```

Now, this gives me a file that looks like this:

```
00 19 05.563 -09 57 53.47 9.92 47.43 -35.62 -301.99
00 24 25.933 -27 01 36.38 7.91 54.87 665.64 83.67
00 39 21.806 +21 15 01.71 5.87 90.42 -461.32 -370.02
00 45 04.894 +01 47 07.88 8.01 46.37 -49.08 -573.23
00 48 22.977 +05 16 50.21 5.72 134.14 757.11 -1141.33
00 51 21.754 +18 44 21.31 9.21 46.79 54.1 -267.14
```

However, I want a file that looks like this:

```
00 19 05.563 -09 57 53.47 9.92  47.43  -35.62  -301.99
00 24 25.933 -27 01 36.38 7.91  54.87  665.64    83.67
00 39 21.806 +21 15 01.71 5.87  90.42 -461.32  -370.02
00 45 04.894 +01 47 07.88 8.01  46.37  -49.08  -573.23
00 48 22.977 +05 16 50.21 5.72 134.14  757.11 -1141.33
00 51 21.754 +18 44 21.31 9.21  46.79   54.10  -267.14
```

Such that everything is right aligned. Can anyone help me figure out an efficient way to do this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You can make different formats for each column by passing a sequence to the 'fmt' keyword argument. Three examples below show different options. More info available at docs.scipy.org.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.random((3,4))
>>> a[1] = a[1] + 10
>>> a
array([[  0.66860114,   0.29021582,   0.47168711,   0.86839242],
       [ 10.41030497,  10.22771623,  10.80389801,  10.6170771 ],
       [  0.47201727,   0.90861352,   0.03952651,   0.67245859]])
>>>
>>> # saved using string format
>>>
>>> np.savetxt('string.txt', a, fmt='%s')
>>> with open('string.txt','r') as f: print(f.read())
...
0.668601144977 0.290215822112 0.471687110847 0.86839242197
10.4103049716 10.2277162318 10.8038980106 10.617077099
0.472017270547 0.9086135154 0.0395265080276 0.672458588797
>>>
>>> # saved using floating format with the "width" parameter = 10
>>>
>>> np.savetxt('fixed.txt',a, fmt='%10.4f')
>>> with open('fixed.txt','r') as f: print(f.read())
...     
    0.6686     0.2902     0.4717     0.8684
   10.4103    10.2277    10.8039    10.6171
    0.4720     0.9086     0.0395     0.6725
>>> 
>>> # saved using format specifier sequence with format for each column
>>> 
>>> np.savetxt('multi.txt',a, fmt=('%5.2f', '%10.4f', '%7.3f', '%12.1f'))
>>> with open('multi.txt','r') as f: print(f.read())
... 
 0.67     0.2902   0.472          0.9
10.41    10.2277  10.804         10.6
 0.47     0.9086   0.040          0.7
```

Comment: Excellent! This worked perfectly. Thank you so much for this incredibly helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is a so called 'fixed-width' csv-file. Since neither numpy nor [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-store-in-csv) is able to export data to a csv-file formatted like this you could do a workaround using the format specifier of [`numpy.savetext()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) if you know the number of digits you have to handle:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import numpy as np

# generate a random array to get some sample data
newlist = np.random.rand(3,2)

# assume you have three decimal digits and seven in total (so four in front of the decimal sign)
np.savetxt('observe.list', newlist, fmt='%7.3f')
```

Giving:

```
  0.021   0.571
  0.471   0.416
  0.177   0.720
```

---

Update due to comment:

```
newlist = np.array([1.5, 10.55555, 0.3, 2, 5.0])
np.savetxt('observe.list', newlist, fmt='%10.5f')
```

Giving:

```
   1.50000
  10.55555
   0.30000
   2.00000
   5.00000
```

Comment: This, however, would only allow me to make one column width, right? Also, it wouldn't necessarily be right-aligned, would it?

Comment: They will be right aligned and filled up with zeros if the decimal digits vary. So the decimal points will be aligned below each other and the digits before the decimal points will somehow flutter around.